# Detecting that a textarea is focused during a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

### Explanation

I have a textarea and a button. When I click the button, I want to insert text into the textarea. However, the text that I insert depends upon the current focus of the texteara. Here are some cases:

### Cases

(As of the time that the button is clicked)

- Textarea focused

  - Insert text where the cursor is, as-is
- Textarea unfocused

  - Insert text at the end of the textarea (ie add a newline to the inserted text)

### Example / Attempt

Here is a fiddle with my example implementation:
https://jsfiddle.net/reL9ro6L/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var $text = $('textarea');

        var currentValue = $text.val(),
            len = currentValue.length,
            isTextAreaFocused = $text.is(':focus'),
            optionalNewline = isTextAreaFocused ? '' : '\n';

        var start = $text[0].selectionStart,
            end = $text[0].selectionEnd,
            beforeText = isTextAreaFocused ? currentValue.substring(0, start) : len,
            afterText = isTextAreaFocused ? currentValue.substring(end) : len;

        var insertedText = 'foo',
            newValue = beforeText + insertedText + afterText + optionalNewline; 

        $text.val(newValue);
    });
})
```

### Problem

I believe that the button focuses before it has a chance to know if the textarea is focused. Is there a hook or way to handle the click event on the button such that I'll know (before it is focused) what is focused?

Off point: I'm using Ember as my framework. I'd really love to see a pure JS / jQuery solution, but I just wanted to place Ember on the table as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to use the `mousedown` event on the button, as it fires before the textarea loses focus.
By the time a `click` event fires, the mouse has been pressed down, and released, and the focus will have shifted to the button instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('button').on({
          mousedown: function() {
            var text              = $('textarea').get(0),
                currentValue      = text.value,
                isTextAreaFocused = text === document.activeElement,
             insertedText      = 'foo',
                start             = text.selectionStart,
                end               = text.selectionEnd,
                beforeText        = currentValue.substring(0, start) || "",
                afterText         = currentValue.substring(end) || "",                   
                newValue          = beforeText + insertedText  + afterText;
             
             text.value = isTextAreaFocused ? newValue : currentValue + insertedText + '\n';
             $(this).data({'focus' : isTextAreaFocused, 'end' : end + insertedText.length});
          },
          mouseup: function() {
              if ( $(this).data('focus') ) {
                  $('textarea').focus().get(0).setSelectionRange($(this).data('end'), $(this).data('end'));
              }    
          }
      });
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 20em;
  height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<button>Insert text</button>
```

Comment: So it'll need to be done in two parts. Get the focus state on mousedown and then add text if the button is clicked/mouseup on button.

Comment: In this case the second part should be handled when the click event is fired because when you use a mouseup event, you can drag your mouse outside the element while having your mouse button clicked down and release it on another element.

Comment: You can get the cursor position. And at second step insert the text at that position.

Comment: Great answer, and super fast too. Thanks @adeneo!